# How to store expiration time?

Tags: php, time

I want to store the expiration time in database. I am using the below code to store expiration time with +1 year.

```
$cdate = time();
$date = $cdate + 365*24*60*60;
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$date);
```

but its not storing the correct time it stores `2014-08-10 07:55:14` but time on storing is `2014-08-10 01:25:14`.
Aslo not sure its Am or Pm .

Thanks.

Comment: it uses your server time to calculate

Comment: So, the calculated value is by 6.5 hours too large. What about local time zones when it comes to display date objects? Just a guess ...

Comment: m doind it offline on wamp .

Comment: Times are using the 24hour system. The american am/pm system is so mind boggling stupid that no sane developer considers using it.

Comment: you can use `strtotime()` to set the expiry date it will create a time stamp.

Comment: Avoid using calculations like `+ 24*60*60` to manipulate timestamps because they can create problems (DST, leap years, etc). Use something like `strtotime('+1 year', time())` to add 1 year to the current time.

Comment: not working     @ironcito

Comment: what is you time zone?what kind of timezone do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Time/date functions in PHP are using timezones to determine your local time. So if your server is in timezone GMT+6 that means that the date() function will return you the date/time that is 6 hours before GMT.

You can check the [date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function manual to find out how PHP is selecting your timezone.

To set your timezone, you can use `date_default_timezone_set()` before calling date function or you can set you php.ini setting `date.timezone` to your timezone.

For the second part of your question - when formatting time using the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function the `H` format character will return 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$timezone1 = "America/Los_Angeles";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone1);

$cdate = time();
$date1 = $cdate + 365*24*60*60;
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s a",$date1);
echo $date;

$timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$cdate = time();
$date1 = $cdate + 365*24*60*60;
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s a",$date1);
echo $date;


?>
```

you can set [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for your location.And also refer this [codepad-FIDDLE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zwIjZW)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it is calculating the time based on your server (local) time.
I suggest you store the time in GMT and then adjust it to your desired timezone as necessary.

You can use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to calculate 1 year from now (no need to calculate it yourself) and use [gmdate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) to get the timestamp in GMT.

```
echo "Next Year in local time: ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 year")) ."\n";
echo "Next year in GMT: " . gmdate ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime ("+1 year")) . "\n";

// Output:
// Next Year in local time: 2014-08-10 15:25:09
// Next year in GMT: 2014-08-10 08:25:09
```